# Conditional Formatting target based on Call Direction - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

I have targets dependent on call direction and need to set up a conditional formatting in a table for the rules to change depending on the call direction when selecting either inbound or outbound in a slicer.

How would I go about setting up the below targets to change in the table dependent on either inbound or outbound selected as can only seem to set up one rule.

[image: Target]